# How to get data from web part in sandbox solution Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I want to get data from web part using sharepoint workflow to fill list item data. How can I solve this problem using sandbox solution? 
I found how that can be done using farm solution but not sandbox:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(""))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
SPFile file = web.GetFile("default.aspx");   
SPLimitedWebPartManager lwpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);                                   SPLimitedWebPartCollection webParts = lwpm.WebParts;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp = webParts[1];                    
string content = (((Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart)(wp)).Content).InnerText;                
}  
}
```